# Como procurar a mesma ocorrência de um termo independente da sua posição em uma string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso criar uma expressão regular que encontre o valor`src=path-da-imagem` em qualquer posição que ele esteja.

Exemplo:

Com a expressão`<img\s(src=\S*)\s(.*?)\/>` consigo achar resultado em:

```
<img src="../../../assets/images/sucesso/chip1.png" alt="Step 1" className="sucesso-bullets" />
<img src="../../../assets/images/logo21.png" alt="Logo OI MOD" width="54" />
```

Mas não consigo achar resultado em:

```
<img class="sc-jKJlTe gpDxyZ" alt="Conheça o Oi Mod, nele você fica no controle! Precisa navegar muito ou quer falar mais? Compre só o que precisar. Troque minutos e internet de acordo com a sua necessidade e confira todos os seus gastos no histórico. Tudo pelo aplicativo, rápido e fácil. Confira todas os benefícios do nosso plano e adquira já." title="Conheça o Oi Mod, precisa navegar muito ou quer falar mais? Compre só o que precisar! Troque minutos e internet sempre que quiser e confira todos os seus gastos no histórico. Tudo pelo app, rápido e fácil. Confira todos os benefícios do Oi Mod, e tenha mais controle e liberdade :)" srcSet="../../../assets/images/oi-mod-tela-compra-troca-1x.gif 600w, ../../../assets/images/oi-mod-tela-compra-troca-2x.gif 1366w, ../../../assets/images/oi-mod-tela-compra-troca-3x.gif 1920w" src="../../../assets/images/oi-mod-tela-compra-troca-1x.gif"/>
```

exemplo funcionando em https://regexr.com/3nm4n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(<img\s[^>]*)(src="[^"]*")(.*>)
```

- `<img\s`: assegura que a tag é IMG
- `[^>]*`: permite qualquer coisa, menos que feche a tag
- `(src="[^"]*")`: atributo `src`
- `(.*>)`: permite qualquer attributo depois antes de fechar a tag

Replace RegExp:

```
$1<< $2 >>$3
```

Porém pode dar falsos positivos.
Lembrando que pode não haver um RegExp satisfatório, e no seu caso, estou quase certo que não conseguirá a RegExp perfeita.

A melhor abordagem talvez seja outra.

Comment: Obrigada @Andre Figueiredo! Mas eu preciso que os dois grupos sejam definidos, para poder recuperar o valor na hora de fazer o replace. Exemplo: $1(grupo com o valor do src e o path) $2(grupo com o restante das propriedades da imagem)